# Sorting products on price and tier price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, sorting, tierprice

In the catalog product list i'm using the sort on price option. But somehow this option doesn't add the Tierprice in the sorting. So when I order on price i see the following:

- € 6,40
- € 6,50
- From € 5,50 (this is the cheapest price)
- € 6,60

And I would like to achieve the following:

- From € 5,50 (this is the cheapest price)
- € 6,40
- € 6,50
- € 6,60

Comment: I take it your "would like to achieve" should be sorted by price, at the moment in your question the two sort lists are the same. I dont think Magento will sort by tier price by default, you will need to detect the tier prices and then manually sort the price data including the tier price.

Comment: Edited my post, but you suggest to build a module for this?

Comment: I think you will need some extra logic somewhere to pull out the tier prices and then add them to the unit price for sorting. In the list view this might add some significant overhead to the processing Magento has to do, especially with a lot of products. A similar question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351576/how-to-use-sort-collection-by-tier-price